# ANDROID: access variable in paused activity

Tags: android

Let's say we have an Android app that consists of a MainActivity, and also a bound intent service (or any other background service that continues to run while MainActivity is paused).

Lets say we have some variables belonging to MainActivity, MainAcitivity.variable1, and MainActivity.variable2.

Is it safe/normal to update these variables from the background service while MainActivity is paused?  I know that it works without errors, but it seems strange to me that it is possible to interact with a class/thread that is "asleep."  If you send multiple updates while Main is paused, do they all end up in a buffer that gets dealt with when Main is resumed?  or do the updates happen immediately?

What technical subject to these questions have to do with?

Thankyou!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't get used to this. simply because your `Service` will not be able to see your `Activity`'s variable when the app is closed.

A very good solution is to cache the changes made by the `Service` in local storage, and use `BroadcastReciever` to update the `Activity` if it is running. In addition to that, the `Activity` should get data from the storage in the `onResume()` method and update the UI accordingly.